How animate with audio visualisation (WEB AUDIO API) in Safari from streaming media element?
I have audio stream in my web application. Need animate dataArray from analyser, but in Safari it is back by getByteFrequencyData() zero array. I know it is bug. But is the another way paining from analyser in Safari?
I am trying another methods of AnalyserNode - not help. I want create animation what depend on stream audio (small wave what change the size by frequency audio). Thanks.
